# Wordpress 'wp_get_archives()' as raw text?

Tags: wordpress, post, archive

in a special case I need the output of `wp_get_archives();` to be just raw text instead of a link. Does anyone know how to do that? I recently checked the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) but also the `'format'=>'custom'` option renders a link.

Thanks in advance!

---- Edit (@vard) ----

`<?php 
    $args2 = array(type'=>'monthly','limit'=>'','format'=>'html','before'=>'','after'=>'','show_post_count'=> false,'echo'=>1,'order'=>'DESC'); 
    echo "<ul>"; 
    wp_get_archives( $args ); 
    echo "</ul>";
?>`

and code from zurb.com:
`add_filter( "get_archives_link", "customarchives_link"); 
function customarchives_link( $x ){ 
   $url = preg_match('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@i', $x, $matches); 
   return $matches[4] == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? preg_replace('@<li@', '<li class="current_page_item"', $x) : $x;
}`

Comment: What about a [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Output is still with <a>-Tags. Seems like Wordpress ignores strip_tags in this case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you set echo parameter at 0? By default wp_get_archives print the return instead of returning it.

Comment: Sorry for my premature comment. I found the way with `strip_tags` just a moment before your answer! First you need to set the `echo` option in the `wp_get_archives()` function to `0` for 'return'. Thanks to @vard for this helpful little snippet even if it's basic php ;)

Comment: @vard: Do you know how I can give every single link of the `wp_get_archives()` output a custom class?

Comment: Check on `get_archives_link` filter - it is not a documented hook, but it allow you to change the output for every link. With some regexp you could add a class. For example [this script](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Add_css_class_to_current_item_in_Wordpress_wp_g-h0B) add a "current" state to each item.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work for me... Here's my code:

Comment: `<?php $args2 = array(type'=>'monthly','limit'=> '','format'=>'html','before'=>'','after'=>'','show_post_count'=> false,'echo'=>1,'order'=>'DESC');
echo "<ul>";
wp_get_archives( $args );
echo "</ul>";`
and 
` add_filter( "get_archives_link", "customarchives_link");
function customarchives_link( $x ){
$url = preg_match('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@i', $x, $matches);
return $matches[4] == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? preg_replace('@<li@', '<li class="current_page_item"', $x) : $x;}`

Comment: Please edit your original question to add the code inside it. It's hard to read in comments.